# How to make evenly-spaced number of different columns for different rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Say I want two rows in Excel: one with three columns at the top, and one with four columns beneath it. I want all three columns at the top to each have the same width as each other, and the four columns at below them also to each have the same width as each other. But, I want both rows to have the same width as well. So it might look something like this (not accurate obviously):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll work with two rows, 12 cells in each:

1. In the first row, select 4 cells, merge them, select another 4, merge them, and then select the other 4 and merge them as well.

   This is the Merge button:

   [image]
2. In the second row, merge every 3 cells.
3. You can adjust the column widths to the desired size and set borders.

Here's a screenshot of what I created:

[image]